# Pandas resample drops column

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas is dropping one of my columns when resampling, and I don't understand why. I've read that this can happen if the columns don't have a proper numerical type, but that isn't the case here:

```
import pandas;

# movements is the target data frame with daily movements
movements = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'amount', 'cash']);
movements.set_index('date', inplace=True);

# df is a movement to add
df = pandas.DataFrame({'amount': 179,
                       'cash':   100.00},
                       index=[pandas.Timestamp('2015/12/31')]);
print(df); print(df.info()); print();

# add df to movements and resample movements
movements = movements.append(df).resample('D').sum().fillna(0);
print(movements); print(movements.info());
```

results in:

```
            amount   cash
2015-12-31     179  100.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1 entries, 2015-12-31 to 2015-12-31
Data columns (total 2 columns):
amount    1 non-null int64
cash      1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 24.0 bytes
None

             cash
2015-12-31  100.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1 entries, 2015-12-31 to 2015-12-31
Freq: D
Data columns (total 1 columns):
cash    1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 16.0 bytes
None
```

I noticed that the drop happens only when `cash` is a float, i.e. if in the code above `cash` is set to `100` (int) rather than `100.00`, then all columns are int and `amount` isn't dropped.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you created movements DF, the datetype for the columns is set to object.

If you set the column types upfront or change it later to numeric types, it should work.

```
movements.append(df).apply(pd.to_numeric).resample('D').sum().fillna(0)
Out[100]: 
            amount   cash
2015-12-31     179   100.0
```

Comment: Thanks! For others experiencing the same issue, I decided to set it up explicitly using `movements = movements.astype(numpy.float);`.